# How to know if Ckeditor anchor is encapsulated within span?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

This is specifically for the developers of CKEditor.

The goal is to know when the cursor is either inside or outside a span of custom atttributes.

When using the Ckeditor, if inserted a custom span like below from a plug-in, occassionally when you stop typing, un focus the textarea and replace your cusor to the end of the line - as though you are continuing typing where you had left off.  The text can either be inside the span or outside with no encapsulation.

Example before unfocus:

```
    <span style="color:blue;line-height:12px;font-size:10px;font-family:arial;" class="master-span">
<span style="color:red;line-height:20px;font-size:18px;font-family:museo;" class="child-span">Text is here</span>
</span>
```

Re-Focus and positioning cusor on screen at the end of "here" and start typing.

```
<span style="color:blue;line-height:12px;font-size:10px;font-family:arial;" class="master-span">
<span style="color:red;line-height:20px;font-size:18px;font-family:museo;" class="child-span">Text is here</span> Text is now outside!!!
</span>
```

What I'm asking is that where would I target my troubleshoot to know when the cursor/anchor is within the span or outside of it i.e. Is there a calculation being made in the code to determine this?

The reason for this enquiry is that the span formmating is extremely important and we can't use a master span in the surrounding textarea as this can be altered by the user.  We find also, that using bulletpoints are troublesome due to the browsers inability to set line-height so ensuring text is always within the span would be a major help.

P.S I've downloaded the source code to see where I could find it.

Many Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking of the text area of any of my CKeditor instances I looked for the parent of the cursor to see if it was an LI node.  This indicating that the cursor had landed outside of my span within a bullet point.  I proceeded to find the most outside Text Node I could find as my assumption is that if the cursor was outside the span thus the user wanted to continue typing from the last character.

In my setup, within a span there can be a number of multiple sub spans with no limitation of number.  So I had to find the most outside span that had a text node at the end (or close to the end).

I did by getting the Node List and reversing the order to find the first text node within the reverse order.  I created a function that could loop the number of span and break upon finding the first text node.

Once I had my text node I then set up ranges and calculated the length of the text in order to place it at the end.  Below is my final solution which works on latest Chrome/FF/IE.

```js
$("#preview-text-3827").on("click", function(){

            var CKEDITOR   = window.parent.CKEDITOR;
            var ck_instance_name = false;
            for ( var ck_instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
                if (CKEDITOR.instances[ck_instance].focusManager.hasFocus){
                    ck_instance_name = ck_instance;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[ck_instance_name];
            var selection = editor.getSelection();
            var parent_attrs = "";
            if (selection.getType() == CKEDITOR.SELECTION_TEXT) {
                parent_attrs = selection.getStartElement();
                if(parent_attrs.getName() == "li"){

                    var nodeList = parent_attrs.getChildren();
                    console.log( "Now Reverse" );
                    for ( var i = nodeList.count() - 1; i > -1; --i ) {
                        //console.log( nodeList.getItem( i).nodeName );
                        var el = nodeList.getItem( i);
                        if(el.$.nodeName == "#text"){
                            // This is the last text but it's inside the li which is WRONG
                        }
                        if(el.$.nodeName == "SPAN"){
                            // This should be the last span
                            // Jump into this span and find the children.
                            var result = retractLiPosition(el);
                            if(result.text == true){
                                var inner = result.result;
                                var text = inner.$.textContent || inner.$.innerText;
                                var length = text.length;
                                var range = editor.createRange();
                                range.setStart( inner , length); 
                                range.setEnd( inner, length); 
                                editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        });


function retractLiPosition(element){
    var returning = new Object();
    returning.result = element;
    returning.text = false;
    var result = element;
    var nodeList = element.getChildren();
    for ( var i = nodeList.count() - 1; i > -1; --i ) {
        var el = nodeList.getItem( i);
        if(el.$.nodeName == "#text"){
            returning.result = el;
            returning.text = true;
            break;
        }
        if(el.$.nodeName == "SPAN"){
            // This should be the last span
            // Jump into this span and find the children.
            returning = retractLiPosition(el);
        }
    }
    return returning;
}


});
```